# CalmQuery <RowLimit> not working

Tags: sharepoint-online

I try to get some files from a folder, inside a folder inside a list. To do this, I try to use a `CalmQuery` with a `RowLimit` because I have lot of files in this folder.

But when I execute the code, it appears that my row limit didn't work.

```
$list = $context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($ListName)
$context.Load($list)

$query = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery
$query.ViewXml = "<View Scope='RecursiveAll'> " +
                "<RowLimit>5000</RowLimit>"+
                "<Query>" +
                    "<OrderBy>"+
                    "<FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef' Ascending='True' />"+
                    "</OrderBy>"+
                    "<Where>" +
                      "<Eq>"+
                        "<FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef' />"+
                        "<Value Type='File'>EDMS API/APICAL Invoice</Value>"+
                      "</Eq>"+
                    "</Where>"+
                "</Query>"+
            "</View>"
$listItems = $list.getItems($query)
$context.Load($listItems)
$context.ExecuteQuery()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely it's not an `RowLimit` issue but rather the `Query` expression itself. The query:

```
<Where>
   <Eq>
       <FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef' />
       <Value Type='File'>{value}</Value>
   </Eq>
</Where>
```

returns items those names match `{value}`, which in turn does not return the files located under a specific folder which url specified in `{value}`.

If you want to include only files located in specific folder you could consider at least the following two approaches.

Assume the following structure:

```
News (sub site)
  |
  Documents (library)
      |
      Archive (folder)
```

Then the following examples demonstrate how to include items from `Archive` folder:

**1** Set folder via `CamlQuery.FolderServerRelativeUrl` property:

```
$query = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery
$query.ViewXml = "<View Scope='RecursiveAll'> " +
                "<RowLimit>20</RowLimit>"+
                "<Query>" +
                    "<OrderBy>"+
                    "<FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef' Ascending='True' />"+
                    "</OrderBy>"+
                "</Query>"+
            "</View>"
$query.FolderServerRelativeUrl = "/News/Documents/Archive"
$listItems = $list.getItems($query)
$context.Load($listItems)
$context.ExecuteQuery()
```

**2** Set folder via `FileDirRef` property

```
$query = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery
$query.ViewXml = "<View Scope='RecursiveAll'> " +
                "<RowLimit>20</RowLimit>"+
                "<Query>" +
                    "<OrderBy>"+
                    "<FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef' Ascending='True' />"+
                    "</OrderBy>"+
                    "<Where>" +
                      "<Eq>"+
                        "<FieldRef Name='FileDirRef' />"+
                        "<Value Type='File'>/News/Documents/Archive</Value>"+
                      "</Eq>"+
                    "</Where>"+
                "</Query>"+
            "</View>"
$listItems = $list.getItems($query)
$context.Load($listItems)
$context.ExecuteQuery()
```